# C++ Multithreaded mergesort not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mergesort

I am new to learning c++ and I am attempting to implement a multi-threaded version of MergeSort. I have compared my algorithms to numerous implementations online and it appears to be nearly identical, however, I am not getting the correct output. The output is even including numbers not found in the original input.

```
using namespace std;
int a[]  = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};  /* target array */
int arrayLen;

void merge(int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int left = low;
    int right = mid+1;

    int b[high-low+1];
    int i, cur = 0;

    while(left <= mid && right <= high) {
        if (a[left] <= a[right])
            b[cur++] = a[left++];
        else
            b[cur++] = a[right++];
    }

    while(left <= mid) b[cur++] = a[left++];
    while(right <= high) b[cur++] = a[right++];
    cur--;
    while (cur >= 0){
        a[low + cur] = b[cur];
        cur--;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int p, int r){


    std::vector<std::future<void>> thread_poolLocal;
    int q;

    if (p >= r) return;
    q = (p+r)/2;

    thread_poolLocal.push_back( std::async(launch::async, mergeSort, p, q));
    thread_poolLocal.push_back( std::async(launch::async, mergeSort, q+1, r));

    merge(p, q, r);
}

int main()
{
    arrayLen = (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
    cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) << endl;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) printf ("%d ", a[i]);
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    mergeSort(0, arrayLen);

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) printf ("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I test this with the simple array shown above, the output is:

```
Length of array = 10
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

0 1 4 2 3 10 5 6 9 7
```

I am compiling the program with: `g++ mergeSortThreaded.cpp -o mergeSortThreaded -std=c++0x -pthread`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push 2 threads into `thread_poolLocal` then immediately call `merge` (which needs the results of those threads) before the threads have ended.

This code can lead to an explosion of threads with larger arrays being sorted because every call to `mergeSort` will create 2 more threads until you get down to empty regions.

Comment: Is there a way I can have it wait for the threads to complete before calling merge? As far as the thread explosion, I'm aware of that and I was just trying to get this to work before refactoring that portion. If I can cause the threads to finish executing before calling merge, that should fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @DonJuma I'm not aware of a standard function to do the waiting, but something along the lines of `for (auto &t: thread_poolLocal) t.wait();` should do the trick.  This will not cure the thread explosion, though, since it is the calls to `mergeSort` that are doing the exploding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually seemed to work as expected. Thanks. The only issue is that the sorted output was: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Where does the zero keep coming from and why does the 10 disappear? Is this also a result of threads not finishing in time? I really appreciate all of the help.

Comment: @DonJuma The zero is because you're accessing one past the end of the `a` array (which is where the 10 ends up).  In your `merge`, `right` is an included element in the range to sort, but in main you pass in `array Len` (10) as the last element when you should be using `arrayLen - 1`.